# How to deploy bash script Custom Runtime AWS Lambda via cloudformation?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a bash script that I want to run through lambda function.

[Can bash script be written inside a AWS Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629574/can-bash-script-be-written-inside-a-aws-lambda-function)
I found this post and tried running bash script by python `os.system('bash_script.sh')`. It works but the python lambda does not wait for the bash script to finish executing.
Then I was about to try the other solution provided in the post which is making the lambda function runtime `Custom`.

However, since I need to deploy the custom runtime lambda function via cloudformation template, I am stuck how to point the files and deploy it correctly.

Here are files I got so far by reading docs and watching videos about it.

###### filename: bootstrap

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail

# Handler format: <script_name>.<bash_function_name>
#
# The script file <script_name>.sh  must be located at the root of your
# function's deployment package, alongside this bootstrap executable.
source $(dirname "$0")/"$(echo $_HANDLER | cut -d. -f1).sh"

while true
do
    # Request the next event from the Lambda runtime
    HEADERS="$(mktemp)"
    EVENT_DATA=$(curl -v -sS -LD "$HEADERS" -X GET "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next")
    INVOCATION_ID=$(grep -Fi Lambda-Runtime-Aws-Request-Id "$HEADERS" | tr -d '[:space:]' | cut -d: -f2)

    # Execute the handler function from the script
    RESPONSE=$($(echo "$_HANDLER" | cut -d. -f2) "$EVENT_DATA")

    # Send the response to Lambda runtime
    curl -v -sS -X POST "http://${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/$INVOCATION_ID/response" -d "$RESPONSE"
done
```

##### filename: hello.sh

```bash
function handler () {
    EVENT_DATA=$1

    # more logics come in here

    RESPONSE="{"statusCode": 200, "body": "Hello from Lambda!"}"
    echo $RESPONSE
}
```

##### cloudformation template

```yaml
CustomRuntimeLambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: custom-runtime-lambda-function
    Description: custom runtime lambda function
    Runtime: provided
    Handler: <WHAT COMES HERE??>
    Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
    Timeout: 60 
    CodeUri: ../src
```

The above 2 files, `bootstrap and hello.sh` are just exact same copies generated by AWS lambda Console.

So I am not sure what to insert in `Handler`. in python or node we put there like `app:handler`
But, what about the custom runtime case? I know that Runtime has two options as `provided` and `provided.al2`. My goal is to just run the bash script as lambda function. And the lambda function will be called by schedule or other aws services like api-gateway or step-function.

I saw the example of custom runtime with a webpack. It was using a specific type of file `Makefile` and under `Metadata` in cloudformation, the path to it was specified.

If that is the configuration I am missing in my cloudformation, then what would be the contents of `Makefile` in the usecase?

Any suggestion or help will be much appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.